# Get data from the dictionary by parameters from a variable in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have dicts with

I get a dictionary from the database with about this structure. And also the path to the desired field of the form - **['extra_fields']['period']** - as a string. Can you please tell me how to turn this string into the path to the data in the dictionary, i.e. into this piece of code in python **clt['extra_fields']['period']** or **clt.get('extra_fields').get('period')**. I'm sitting here thinking and can't figure out the best way to do it? The line with the path to the data can be anything, not just as in the example (so hardcoded is not an option)

```
clt = {
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test",
        "phone": "123",
        "client_id": 123,
        "email": "test@mail.ru",
        "father_name": "",
        "source": "test",
        "extra_fields": {
            "amount": 50000,
            "period": 90,
            "utm_source": "TEST_SOURCE",
            "utm_campaign": "TEST_CAMPAIGN",
            "keyword": "TEST_CREATIVE_ID"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can traverse the dictionary as you intend to, either by square brackets notation or by `.get`, but first you must turn the stored string into a dict with `json.loads`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

lets say path is correct so you can use it with `eval` or you can parse the keys and then using those parsed keys  you can access the data.

example with `eval` is as, (considering dictionary access path is correct

```
>>> clt = {
...         "first_name": "test",
...         "last_name": "test",
...         "phone": "123",
...         "client_id": 123,
...         "email": "test@mail.ru",
...         "father_name": "",
...         "source": "test",
...         "extra_fields": {
...             "amount": 50000,
...             "period": 90,
...             "utm_source": "TEST_SOURCE",
...             "utm_campaign": "TEST_CAMPAIGN",
...             "keyword": "TEST_CREATIVE_ID"
...         }
...     }
>>> 
>>> path = "['extra_fields']['period']"
>>> 
>>> data = eval(f"clt{path}")
>>> data
90
>>>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Is there any way to translate this into .get().get().get()... ?

Comment: @NatalyFirstova well you need a parser for that, like, you need to extract keys from the path and then use those keys in order and put them in `.get` method one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the path to a list of paths using regex, and get the value using recursion

```
def get_value(_clt, path):
    value = _clt.get(path[0])
    if type(value) is dict:
        return get_value(value, path[1:])
    return value

path = "['extra_fields']['period']"
path = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)]', path.replace("'", ''))
print(get_value(clt, path)) # 90

path = "['last_name']"
path = re.findall(...)
print(get_value(clt, path)) # test
```